# How to use bootstrap - switch

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I read a lot in this forum about dealing with checkboxes. I tried following solutions but nothing worked so far:

```
$('#id_1').prop('checked',true);
$('#id_1').prop('checked',false);

$('#id_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('#id_1').removeAttr('checked');

document.getElementById('id_1').checked = true;
document.getElementById('id_1').checked = false;

document.getElementById('id_1').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
document.getElementById('id_1').removeAttribute('checked');
```

I am getting the feeling, that I have to reload the element. If so, how can I reload a single element using its id?

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_1" class="bootstrap-switch" data-on-label="ON" data-off-label="OFF" checked="checked">
```

Happy for some help.

///////////////////////////////////////

Found the answer to work with the class: bootstrap-switch. See below:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

// Set actual state

```
$('#id_1').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
```

// eventlistener from Bernhard (see below):

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  console.log(event.target.checked);
  $(this).attr('data-switch-value', event.target.checked);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"? please tell us what is not working. Also please use the `<>` snippet tool and create a working demo of the problem

Comment: The Bootstrap switch is just a UI wrapper around a standard checkbox control. You interact with it as you would any other checkbox. If any of the above methods aren't working for you then there must be an underlying problem in your code. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Thank you Rory. I logged the checkbox: `console.log($('#id_1'))`. The `0: input#id_1.bootstrap-switch` property `checked` is set correctly (true or false). The displayed bootstrap-switch does not change accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide details regarding *exactly* which plugin(s) you're using for this?  According to [bootstrap-4 switch page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#switches) (as you've tagged bootstrap-4) it doesn't use `class="bootstrap-switch"` so I'm guessing you have another component or it's not bootstrap-4.   A google for "bootstrap-switch" provides what appear to be numerous *different* plugins.

Comment: this should absolutely work for normal checkbox: `$('#id_1').prop('checked',true);`

Comment: Just tried to set up a JSFiddle to test your code but can't work out what "switch" you mean. As already requested, pls edit your question and clarify what plugins etc you are using.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Bootstrap 4 has a class bootstrap-switch. To make use of the switch, there is an API documentation. To set the switch on the client side you can use: $('#id_1').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);. To set an eventlistener I use the answer provided from Bernhard below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?
This example works.

```js
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();

$("[name='my-checkbox']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  console.log(event.target.checked);
  $(this).attr('data-switch-value', event.target.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/djibe/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/djibe/bootstrap-switch@6a41c824782c514fd5e09b6683f852a9c9b2a997/dist/css/bootstrap4/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
```

If you like to play. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/qxjd0res/2/

Comment: Thank you Bernhard! It runs perfect. Also found the API documentation with all the features.